# Web fonts not rendering in supportive email clients

Tags: email, webfonts, typekit

It's my understanding that the following email clients DO support web fonts:

AOL Mail
Native Android mail app (not Gmail app)
Apple Mail
iOS Mail
Outlook 2000
Outlook.com App

However, it's not rendering correctly in anything other than Apple Mail and AOL Mail.
I'm using the @import method to pull Bebas Neue from Adobe Typekit:
[@import section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkzQC.png)

and then calling it with inline CSS styling:

[CSS call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv8lp.png)

Am I missing something key here? Why is it not rendering correctly in the other supportive clients?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that font in the style or as a google web font link in the head. 
Example below:

```
@media screen {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'DINPro-Light';
    src: url('http://yourfont.com/fonts/din/DINPro-Light.eot');
    src: url('http://yourfont.comfonts/din/DINPro-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://yourfont.comfonts/din/DINPro-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('http://yourfont.comfonts/din/DINPro-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://yourfont.comfonts/din/DINPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://yourfont.comfonts/din/DINPro-Light.svg#DINPro-Light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```